# How to create a slinky animation in blender?

Tags: animation, rigging

I tried using mesh deform, and using the curve modifier. I am a total beginner so please forgive any obvious things I might've missed.
Here's the link to what I want to recreate in blender: 
https://youtu.be/Dyn4O6WP3Jc

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VooYlKaqnQ I found this tutorial on youtube. Maybe it can help you

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kldKlTZeoIE another fun tutorial that I just found. It's a bit (ok, *extremely*) fast, but maybe it can help some advaced blender users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the mesh of your slinky using the [screw modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html) on a crossection mesh. Then you want to use a [Bézier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/curves/structure.html) to [deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html) your slinky. [image: small test] You can animate the whole thing by applying [shape keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html) to your curve. You can simply [key frame](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/animation.html?highlight=keyframe#keyframes) these.

You will encounter a problem regarding how far your object stretches along the curve. I have no solution but key framing the z scale yet. But I think you can calculate the length of your Bézier and write a driver for it if it is too much to animate. Which is way more difficult for a beginner.

a [lattice](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/lattice.html) might improve the destribution of your slinky along the curve.